# localhost redirects to http://www.localhost:8000/

Tags: linux, firefox, google-chrome, localhost, hosts

I have a problem with my google chrome and firefox (the only 2 browsers I have)

When run my django server with `./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` and when I go to chrome or firefox and enter `localhost:8000` chrome redirects to http://www.localhost:8000/

do you know what is the problem??

my hosts file is:

```
#
# /etc/hosts: static lookup table for host names
#

#<ip-address>   <hostname.domain.org>   <hostname>
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain   localhost arch
127.0.0.1   example.com
```

Comment: Just enter `http://localhost:8000/` once, and bookmark the page.

Comment: for rare that it sounds it is not working... I enter: `http://localhost:8000/` and redirects to: `http://www.localhost:8000/`
tha is the problem actually

Comment: Firefox and chrome normally don't do that. You need to sniff your http traffic  in order to see what's really happening. Install an add-on like LiveHTTPHeaders and see what kind of redirect, if any, you are receiving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the problem was solved adding this line:

```
::1     localhost.localdomain   localhost arch
```

in the `/etc/hosts` file.

Answer (score 0):

After setting `PREPEND_WWW = False` and clear the browser cache, it works in Firefox and Chromium.